# What Regex code to use for .jpg extension in lower and upper case?

Tags: regex

Not being a Regex expert, I was wondering in what way I have to change the regex code so it will also match the .jpg extension in capitals at the end (.JPG)? This is the code:

```
^(\d+(?:_\d+)?\.jpg$)
```

See test here: http://regex101.com/r/aV1aD8

Thanks!

Comment: If your regex tool supports `i` modifier then just add `/i` at the end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you cannot use a case independent option then use

```
^(\d+(?:_\d+)?\.[Jj][Pp][Gg]$)
```

This uses `J` or `j` then `P` or `p`, etc. Hence it will match any variation of capitals, including `Jpg`, jPg`and`JpG`.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianHHH your code workes and still keeps all the restrictions: http://regex101.com/r/hW3kP4

Comment: There are two down votes on this answer. I would like to know why they were given so I can improve my future answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(\d+(?:_\d+)?\.jpe?g$)/i
```

matches `jpg`, `JPG`, `jpeg` or `JPEG`
case insensitive `/i`

Comment: thanks, the code is used in the File input in SSIS'08, I tried using your code since it also handles jpeg/JPEG which is great, unfortunately, SSIS Foreach loop accepts the code, uses it, but then doesn't do anything in the file system task. It does process the version of AdrianHHH in the loop & file system task. Is there a way to get the optional e in? Like:  ^(\d+(?:_\d+)?\.[Jj][Pp][Ee]?[Gg]$)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your fiddle, I'm assuming that you're using PHP, so you can just add a /i modifier to your regex:

```
/^(\d+(?:_\d+)?\.jpg$)/i
^                     ^^  added delimiters and i modifier
```

[Updated fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/iF0aS3)

Comment: Don't forget that optional "e" for those pesky people who still for whatever reason use the "jpeg" extension.